# How to avoid producing a blocky image using gdals rgb2pct?

Tags: gdal

I want to create clean single band 8 bit images from RGB using gdal rgb2pct. Due to the dithering algorithm in rgb2pct the resulting image shows very blocky areas producing many different coloured pixels although the source image for these areas are single coloured. My only workaround is to first use the ArcMap copy-raster tool to produce a single band image using the option rgb-to-colormap and then use this raster as a pallete in rgb2pct. This ESRI Tool produces a clean undithered image.

Is there any other way to achieve this only using gdal?

Screeshot and link to data below:

[image: blocky image]

[Data download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v-4IVQ6cp0XPIqeqvI3fnn61y8ND1FN9/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Add a link to test data and screen captures about the issue.

Comment: I think that rgb2pct is decreasing the image quality too much and that is not only because of the Floyd-Steinberg dithering. IrfanView Decrease Color Depth tool has also the option to use Floyd-Steinberg but it does not make similar changes to the image. Dithering is done with this https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/35c07b18316b4b6d238f6d60b82c31e25662ad27/alg/gdaldither.cpp